How to valdate items from array in Laravel
I have a question, how can I validate the elements of an array against each other in a request? For example, I want the documents.*.end_date to be required if the selected document has a property called vigency set to true.
        return [
        'documents' => 'required|array',
        'documents.*.id' => 'required|numeric|exists:documents,id',
        'documents.*.start_date' => 'required|date',
        'documents.*.end_date' => ['nullable','after_or_equal:documents.start_date'],
        'assigment_id' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'exists:assigments,id',
            new ActiveRule('assigments'),
            new AssigmentBelongsToAdminOrIsAuthenticatedUser
        ]
    ];


Check this out: https://echebaby.com/blog/2021-12-30-laravel-validate-true-and-false-as-booleans/

The required_if rule seems to be what you're after. 'documents.*.end_date' => ['required_if:documents.*.vigency,true']

@IGP but the array does not contain vigency, I have to get the vigency from the documents table

And to get the vigency I need each document id form the array

you can use the after(), and check that after validation

I think this problem gets solved nicely with sometimes. I left an example below. https://laravel.com/docs/validation#complex-conditional-validation

You could create a new Rule that implements the DataAwareRule Contract and use it in your FormRequest. Although you could also just use a conditional validation with sometimes.
use App\Models\Document;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Fluent;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class YourFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'documents'              => ['required', 'array', 'min:1'],
            'documents.*.id'         => ['required', 'exists:documents,id'],
            'documents.*.start_date' => ['required', 'date'],
        ];
    }

    public function withValidator(Validator $validator): void
    {
        $validator->sometimes(
            ['documents.*.end_date'],
            ['required', 'after_or_equal:documents.*.start_date'],
            function (Fluent $input, Fluent $item): bool {
                return Document::query()
                    ->where('id', $item->id)
                    ->where('vigency', true)
                    ->exists();
            },
        );
    }
    
}

